# Javascript redirect different link with ;

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am having that problem that I am getting a different redirect link:

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout(function() {
             window.location.href = "<%= @link.link %>";
            }, 1000);
</script>
```

The @link.link is:

```
<%= @link.link %> = http://tracking.euroads.dk/system/tracking.php?sid=1&cpid=3082&adid=544034&acid=4123&eatrackid=47402
```

The page that the user gets redirected to is:

```
http://tracking.euroads.dk/system/tracking.php?sid=1&amp;cpid=3152&amp;adid=551367&amp;acid=4123&amp;eatrackid=474027
```

The right url:

```
http://tracking.euroads.dk/system/tracking.php?sid=1&cpid=3082&adid=544034&acid=4123&eatrackid=47402
```

As you can see there are ; and that shouldnt there not be

I have also this javascript on the page:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function showProgressDots(numberOfDots) {

    var progress = document.getElementById('progressDots');

    switch(numberOfDots) {
        case 1:
            progress.innerHTML = '.';
            timerHandle = setTimeout('showProgressDots(2)',200);
            break;
        case 2:
            progress.innerHTML = '..';
            timerHandle = setTimeout('showProgressDots(3)',200);
            break;
        case 3:
            progress.innerHTML = '...';
            timerHandle = setTimeout('showProgressDots(1)',200);
            break;
    }
}
window.setTimeout('showProgressDots(1)',100);
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Your link is being parsed for HTML Entities.  All ampersands are being swapped out for `&amp;`.  What is that ASP?  You should look into turning off the parser.  Wherever that link is generated.

Comment: The semicolon comes from '&amp;' and that is the url encoded form of '&' the ampersands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this `<%= @link.link %>` and your username I presume you are using Rails.

Try to change this row:

```
window.location.href = "<%= @link.link %>";
```

to this

```
window.location.href = "<%= raw @link.link %>";
```

Your url is htmlencoded. Which means your `&` characters becomes `&amp;`. `raw` should fix that I think

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby on Rails 3, try replace

```
window.location.href = "<%= @link.link %>";
```

with

```
window.location.href = "<%= @link.link.html_safe %>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't solve your ampersand issue (see my comment above).  But I couldn't pass up a chance to simplify that javascript function:

```
function showProgressDots(numberOfDots) {
    var i, dots = '', progress = document.getElementById('progressDots');
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDots; i++) {
        dots += '.';
    }
    timerHandle = setTimeout(function() {
        var increment = numberOfDots < 3 ? numberOfDots + 1 : 1;
        progress.innerHTML = dots;
        showProgressDots(increment);
    }, 200);
}
window.setTimeout(function() { showProgressDots(1); },100);
```